# Can I configure the DNN Search to be Section 508/WCAG 2.0 compliant?

Tags: accessibility, dotnetnuke, section508, wcag2.0, dotnetnuke-8

I have several DNN (DotNetNuke) portals that use the DNN Search token on their respective skins. When I run a Section 508 / WCAG 2.0 accessibility report, it indicates that the DNN Search does not meet Section 508 / WCAG 2.0 guidelines.

Has anyone ran into this issue? If so, what steps would you recommend to remedy the problem?

I am using DNN Evoq Content 8.5

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what the problem is, but there are things that can be modified for compliance.  If I were to do this, I would clone the Search skin object and modify it (presumably the markup for the object) for compliance.

If the Search Results is the problem, you could do something similar.

Finally, I would contact DNN Corp. about this.  It's my understanding that compliance is a target of DNN (and Evoq) version 9.  Their goal is to be compliant "out of the box" and that does include Search.  I'm not sure where that stands, but it's worth asking.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I solved my own issue, but the underlying DNN CMS is does not meet current WCAG 2.0 Requirements for Level AA nor does it meet U.S. Section 508 requirements. What I'm currently doing is modifying the CMS to meet the requirements. However, I definitely am reaching out to DNN in regards to this.